# how to implement straight two way merge sort with fold or reduce

Tags: javascript, sorting, mergesort

I had found an interesting merge sort called `straight to way merge sort`, and in JavaScript write code like this.

```js
function msort(arr) {
  const sorted = arr.map(a => [a]);
  while (sorted.length > 1) {
    sorted.push(merge(...sorted.splice(0, 2)));
  }
  return sorted.length ? sorted.shift() : [];
}

function merge(left, right) {
  const res = [];
  while (left.length && right.length) {
    res.push(left[0] < right[0] ? left.shift() : right.shift());
  }
  return res.concat(left, right);
}

console.log(msort([12,34,1,3,49,54,67]));
```

But I want to know, can I use `fold` or `reduce` to write it in a more functional way?

Comment: There is no Array.prototype.fold, (see [*Properties of Array.prototype*](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object)), what do you think it does? BTW, this looks very inefficient.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it's inefficient. And the fold just like the `foldl` in Haskell. But let's assume array in javascript were implemented in Link List.

Comment: I mean, I want to find a way more functional like Haskell, but I can't write Haskell  code… So I use JavaScript to implement it.